# Alternative to innerHTML for IE

Tags: innerhtml

I create HTML documents that include proprietary tags for links that get transformed into standard HTML when they go through our publishing system. For example:

```
<LinkTag contents="Link Text" answer_id="ID" title="Tooltip"></LinkTag>
```

When I'm authoring and reviewing these documents, I need to be able to test these links in a browser, before they get published. I wrote the following JavaScript to read the attributes and write them into an `<a>` tag:

```
var LinkCount = document.getElementsByTagName('LinkTag').length; 
for (i=0; i<LinkCount; i++) { 

var LinkText = document.getElementsByTagName('LinkTag')[i].getAttribute('contents');
var articleID = document.getElementsByTagName('LinkTag')[i].getAttribute('answer_id');
var articleTitle = document.getElementsByTagName('LinkTag')[i].getAttribute('title');

document.getElementsByTagName('LinkTag')[i].innerHTML = '<a href="publishing_system_url_id='+ articleID +' title="' + articleTitle + '">' + LinkText + '</a>';
}
```

This works great in Firefox, but not in IE. I've read about the innerHTML issue with IE and imagine that's the problem here, but I haven't been able to figure a way around it. I thought perhaps jQuery might be the way to go, but I'm not that well versed in it.

This would be a huge productivity boost if I could get this working in IE. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your 'LinkTag' element a DIV?

Comment: What exactly is it that doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

innerHTML only works for things INSIDE of the open/close tags. So for instance if your `LinkTag[i]` is an `<a>` element, then putting `innerHTML="<a .... > </a>` would put that literally between the `<a tag=LinkTag>` and `</a>`.

You would need to put that in a DIV. Perhaps use your code to draw from links, then place the corresponding HTML code into a div.

```
var LinkCount = document.getElementsByTagName('LinkTag').length; 
for (i=0; i<LinkCount; i++) { 

var LinkText = document.getElementsByTagName('LinkTag')[i].getAttribute('contents');
var articleID = document.getElementsByTagName('LinkTag')[i].getAttribute('answer_id');
var articleTitle = document.getElementsByTagName('LinkTag')[i].getAttribute('title');

document.getElementsById('MyDisplayDiv')[i].innerHTML = '<a href="publishing_system_url_id='+ articleID +' title="' + articleTitle + '">' + LinkText + '</a>';
```

This should produce your HTML results within a div. You could also simply append the other `LinkTag` elements to a single DIV to produce a sort of "Preview of Website" within the div.

```
document.getElementsById('MyDisplayDiv').innerHTML += '<a href="publishing_system_url_id='+ articleID +' title="' + articleTitle + '">' + LinkText + '</a>';
```

Note the `+=`. Should append your HTML fabrication to the DIV with ID "MyDisplayDiv". Your list of `LinkTag` elements would be converted into a list of HTML elements within the div.

Comment: Apparently the "LinkTag" is exactly that - a tag that looks like `<LinkTag ...>`, not a standard HTML tag.

Comment: Which is fine, as long as the `document.getElementsByTagName('LinkTag')[i].getAttribute()` function works. He uses this javascript to convert his special tags into HTML readable tags. The only problem is if Javascript doesn't recognize <LinkTag> as an element.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. You're right that the <LinkTag> tag is exactly as listed above. Not sure if this matters, but it's also empty (nothing between open and close tags). The getAttribute() function does work for extracting the attributes in IE and FF. What fails--in IE only, FF works fine--is inserting the <a> tag construction using the .innerHTML assignment. I'll try your 'MyDisplayDiv' adjustments and see how that goes.

Comment: Again, inserting the `<a>` tag in an `.innerHTML` statement, if I'm not mistaken, will produce a string; not necessarily an element. You must ensure that what you are placing it into can interpret the string as HTML (like a DIV). Using `.innerHTML` on the <a> element itself will only produce `<a id=original>"INNER HTML HERE <a id=new>LINK WITHIN A LINK</a></a>`

Answer (score 0):

[DOM functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/) might be considered more "clean" (and faster) than simply replacing the innerHTML in cases like this. Something like this may work better for you:

```
// where el is the element you want to wrap with <a link.
newel = document.createElement('a')
el.parentNode.insertBefore(newel,prop);
el = prop.parentNode.removeChild(prop);
newel.appendChild(prop);
newel.setAttribute('href','urlhere');
```

Similar code worked fine for me in Firebug, it should wrap the element with `<a> ... </a>`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script I have on my blog which you can find here: http://blog.funelr.com/?p=61 anyways take it a look it automatically fixes ie innerHTML errors in ie8 and ie9 by hijacking ie's innerHTML property which is "read-only" for table elements and replacing it with my own.

Answer (score 0):

I have this xmlObject:

```
<c:value i:type="b:AccessRights">ReadAccess WriteAccess AppendAccess AppendToAccess CreateAccess DeleteAccess ShareAccess AssignAccess</c:value>
```

I find value use this:    `responseXML.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic",'value')[0].firstChild.data`

Answer (score -1):

1. This one is the best : `elm.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', str );`
2. In case your element size is very small :`elm.innerHTML += str;`